# Can't load rule as lexer or parser - Antlr4

Tags: python-3.x, antlr, antlr4

I am getting an error `Can't load Chat as lexer or parser`
when running the command `grun Chat chat`

I am following the instructions at https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/#setup-antlr

Using python on a Mac OS and here's my bash_profile details :-

```
export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"
alias antlr4='java -Xmx500M -cp "/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.Tool'
alias grun='java -Xmx500M -cp "/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
```

Commands run :-
To create the python files: `antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 Chat.g4`

The following files are created when the above command is run :-

```
chat.interp, chat.tokens, chatLexer.interp, ChatLexer.py, ChatLexer.tokens, ChatListener,py, ChatParse.py
```

To run the grun tool: `grun Chat chat`
I tried different parser rules but get the same error.

Comment: Can you post all the commands you ran (to compile the grammar and java files) and their output? Which .class files exist in your current directory?

Comment: Added the required information in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

`grun` is a Java tool that expects the lexer and parser to exist as Java classes that it can load and instantiate. So you'll need to generate Java code from the grammar and then compile it using `javac` before you can use `grun`.

If you can't generate Java from your grammar (because your grammar contains Python actions for example), you can't use `grun`.